# use SID instead of user name in console command

Tags: windows, command, sid

i have a console command that i need to run using SID instead of User name. currently i suspect that the command is failing because the system locale is not English.

cmd.exe /q /c "for /L %i in (000,1,8010) do netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:%i/ user=Everyone"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, for such command that you present in your example, you must use the string username.

I'm not sure of your case, but I found myself in a similar situation where I need to run IIS under lower ports as a regular user, and I was using some similar command. For sure the `Everyone` username works as long your systems is in English.

I searched the internet and it would be too much complicated on Windows to get the username based on the SID. The `Everyone` user has a [well known](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) SID which is `S-1-1-0`.

With some programs, such as [PsTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx), you can run a similar command such as

`SidToName.exe S-1-1-0`

to retrieve a user's SID. For my case, it outputs

`[WellKnownGroup]: \Todos`

because my system is currently in Portuguese, where `Todos` means `Everyone`; thus I just need to get the `Todos` part. Yet I found it too cumbersome to manipulating strings with DOS batch files.

**Turned out that I simplified my case** by running the command with the `%USERNAME` windows variable, since I just needed to allow my own user to run the IIS on lower ports. If that it your case, it will do the trick. **My command looks like**:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://mylocalsite.app:80/ user=%USERNAME%`

If the `%USERNAME%` does not suffice, you will have to do some string manipulation as a way of getting the language-agnostic name for `Everyone`.